# custom JPanel not updating

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d

the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PaintWindow {

private JFrame frame;
private aJPanel panel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PaintWindow window = new PaintWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PaintWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new aJPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel.stam();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class aJPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8874943072526915834L;
    private Graphics g;

    public aJPanel() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        System.out.println("paint");
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
        this.g = g;

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("paintComponent");
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
        this.g = g;
    }

    public void stam() {
        System.out.println("stam");
        this.g.fillRect(40, 40, 40, 40);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
}
```

what I want to do is paint *custom shapes* (lines, rectangles etc) after the user clicks a button or triggers a mouse event. but calling `aJPanel.stam()` does not show the rectangle its supposed to. I am fairly new to `JPanel`. any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Remove `public void paint(Graphics g) {` 2) `private Graphics g;` Don't attempt to cache an object that is transient. 3) See the examples in [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for how to do it properly.

Comment: 4) In fact, replace `private Graphics g;` with `private Shape s;` then replace `this.g.fillRect(40, 40, 40, 40);
        this.repaint();` with `s = new Rectangle(..);
        this.repaint();` then replace `g.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
        this.g = g;` with (something like) `if (s!=null) { Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; g2.draw(s); }` and it should work, on button press.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

1. class names should start with a capital letter
2. class names should be descriptive.

"aJPanel" does not follow either of the above.

> but calling aJPanel.stam() does not show the rectangle its supposed to

See [Custom Painting Apporoaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do dynamic painting:

1. Add objects to a List and iterate the List to paint all the objects
2. Paint directly to a BufferedImage and then paint the BufferedImage

The examples add the Rectangle by dragging the mouse, but you can easily add Rectangles by just invoking the `addRectangle(...)` method when you click a button.